# How to change text of navigation bar (UISearchController)?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, navigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I have created a navigation bar with `UISearchController`.

Below is my code:

```
@IBAction func showSearchController(sender: AnyObject) {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultController)
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    /*
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "hhhhhhhhhhh"
    searchController.navigationItem.title = "hhhhhhhhhhh"
    searchController.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "hhhhhhhh"    -->i try these codes for to change*/

    self.presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But I can't change the text.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to change the string that reads "search" in your screenshot above? And, is `showSearchController(sender:)` currently wired up to the magnifying glass bar button item? If so, then you want to change the `title` of `self` I believe. Where `self` is the view controller that implements `showSearchController(sender:)`.

Comment: yes , i want change title itself can you give the code of what you said , please ?(with showSearchController (sender:)

Answer (score 1):

```
var searchTextField = searchController.searchBar.valueForKey("_searchField") as! UITextField
searchTextField.placeholder = "Your Custom Text"
```

[image]Use this to change your place holder text

Comment: with your code I can access for text of searchBar but i want to change text of navigation (in picture in place of 'search') , Excuse me if i was not able to write my problem

Comment: can you help in this case please ?

Comment: the text shown in image is the place holder of the search bar which you added in navigation bar correct?

Comment: no its the title of navigation bar (place holder will be appear when i press the search icon ) i want to change "search"title

Comment: it's not the title of navigation bar

Comment: it's your place holder

Comment: please post full screen shot

Comment: please check above screen shot

Comment: no it is not at all place holder it is title for navigation bar

Comment: look when i press the search button (in right of navigation bar) the search bar will appear but i dont want this , i want change text of navigation bar ("search")

Comment: set it to navigation bar title then.

Comment: have i can do that programmatically because i want change in every search ?? can you help me ??

Comment: self.title = "some title"

Comment: write this in searchresultcontroller call's viewdidload

Comment: self.navigationItem.title = "The title"
try this then

Comment: it doesnt work ( note : i have two navigation bar i added two navigation bar from object library = i add manually without navigation controller)

Comment: why you need to add 2 navigation bar

Comment: plz create a sample and upload so i can check as this is getting very confusing for me

Comment: for my map application

Comment: plz upload sample

Comment: i upload it in question

Comment: sample project buddy